# Can knocking noises caused by anti roll drop links be intermittent or just not detectable until they get worse?

Tags: suspension, testing, knock

So I was getting a knocking noise from under car and mechanic 1(who just had axle stands i.e. no ramp) said its either the anti roll bar or ball joint and there was no way of knowing which you just needed to go by elimination.

Took it to mechanic 2 who put on ramp tested and said there was no noises coming from anti roll bars or ball joints and so it must be driveshaft.

Took it to mechanic 3 for mot who didnt find the noise either though I told them to check the suspension carefully. Day after mot I didnt hear much knocking but second day it was knocking again wildly.  took it to mechanic 4 who was able to identify knocking from anti roll bar drop links by shaking on ramp.  I also took it to kwik fit who I think had more sophisticated ramps and it generated the knock sound without anybody having to use hands.

As you can see the drop links were making knocking sounds from the beginning however they were missed by physical inspection by mechanic 2, mechanic 3 in an mot and then a day after mot do the other mechanics find it. in light of all these I'd like to ask:

1)  In the early days where an anti roll bar drop links are causing a knocking sound, is it the case that you may not be able to detect it by moving on a ramp even though you hear it when driving?
If so what is the reason for this, human hands cannot generate the power of the car moving around?

2) Are the ramps used by kwik fit more sophisticated and able to generate better movement and if so, had I gone to them first they might they have found it?

3) Can these the anti roll bar linkage knock sound(or other similar suspension sounds) be intermittent for any reason, such that maybe it could be detected on a ramp/is more noisy on uneven roads at one time/day but not another? like I say at times the noise has been severe at other times not so noticeable etc.

Thanks.

Comment: My answers din’t seem to be helpful to you so I won’t.

Comment: @SolarMike sorry I do not know what you are referring to.  I've checked your previous answers only one relates to drop links where you state links are known for causing noises e.g rattles and clonks which is fine.  But this is not a duplicate question and is asking why on physical inspection the noises are not being generated.  Apologise if I have missed something.

Comment: @SolarMike if you are referring to my comment on your answer about why the use of tie rod, well that was a sub question in the original question which you did not answer but that doesn't mean you didn't answer the main question.